# How to give an error in one of the cells when both cells contain certain text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, A1 and A2 both contains the text "Upper Case", and I can't allow A1 and A2 to both contain "Upper Case", so I want the excel to give an error in A2

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOm8e.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOm8e.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQK5M.png

Comment: How to display the error for A2? Conditional formatting or error result in B2?

Comment: @Lee 's answer plus also in the case that ``Value(A2)`` is derived from a formula, then in  ``A2`` this would work``=IF(formula=A1, "errorMsg", formula)``